# Which FIFA World Cup qualifiers have never faced each other in the final round of any FIFA World Cup tournament?

Tags: football, world-cup

Which FIFA World Cup qualifiers have never faced each other in the final round of any FIFA World Cup tournament?

Comment: You should narrow down the question.. There will be a lot of countries that never faced each other. Just take Iceland and Panama from the 2018 World Cup. They both got eliminated in the group stage, so they faced three teams and never faced one of the other countries (~80 countries have at least one appearance), because it was their first World Cup appearance.

Comment: 79 countries participated overall, 21 of those (Cuba, Indonesia, Wales, Israel, DR Congo, East Germany, Haiti, Kuwait, Canada, Iraq, United Arab Emirates. Jamaica, China PR, Angola, Togo, Trinidad and Tobago, Ukraine, Slovakia, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Iceland, Panama) have participated only once. So there are **at least** `21*(79-1-7) = 1491` pairs that were never played (*`-1` because a team can't play itself. `-7` because a team can play against max. 7 opponents in one edition*). This question is too broad.

Comment: Considering each team only plays a maximum total of 7 games now each tournament (less in many past tournaments), indeed a lot of missing matchups of even fairly common teams. Brazil has been in all 21 Cups, but still only 109 games vs 46 opponents (looks like they used inherited records for countries that now cease to exist). Would be nice to get an idea of what common competitors haven't played. But couldn't find a site that allowed for sorting team records just for World Cups. Wikipedia articles like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil_at_the_FIFA_World_Cup) may be some hope.

Comment: Looks like Brazil (21 World Cups) have never played South Korea (10 World Cups)...Germany (19 World Cups) have never played USSR/Russia (11 World Cups)... and Portugal are relatively new at sustained success, only apparently having managed 7 World Cups... but have not yet played Argentina, Italy, or Yugoslavia/Serbia.  Those look to be some of the more standout ones from a quick manual scanning.  Obviously a lot more for the teams that are less common.